# Angular bracket notation (physics)

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, sde

In a few papers I have seen the following notation:
$$
\langle X_t \rangle
$$
Also, in Bergomi's book, at page 8, we have the following equality:
$$
\biggr\langle \int_0^T e^{-rt}s^2 \frac{d^2P_{\hat{\sigma}}}{dS^2}\sigma^2_t dt \biggr\rangle=\biggr\langle\int_o^Te^{-rt}S^2\frac{d^2P_{\hat{\sigma}}}{dS^2}\hat{\sigma}dt\biggr\rangle
$$
What does the angular bracket symbol mean? Is it the expectation under the risk neutral measure? Does its meaning vary as a function of the contect, or does it always has the same precisely-defined meaning?

**Edit:** It seems the notation originates from physics. I'd be very grateful if someone can explain what this notation means in physics.

**Edit:** To give more context, I quote from Bergomi's book :
***Indeed, to a good approximation, the variance of returns scales linearly with their time scale, thus $\langle \delta S^2 \rangle$ is of order $\delta t$ and $\delta S$ is of order $\sqrt{\delta t}$.*** The book had not specified any dynamic for $(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$.

**Edit:** Related question [What do angle brackets (⟨⟩ ) mean in mathematics/statistics (autocorrelations)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365161/what-do-angle-brackets-langle-rangle-mean-in-mathematics-statistics-autoc)

**Edit:** Also on Bergomi's book, on p. 9, we are told:
*Let is write the daily return $r_i$ as:
$$
r_i=\sigma_i\sqrt{\delta t}z_i
$$
where $\sigma_i$ is the realized volatility for day $i$, and $z_i$ is centered and has unit variance: $\langle z_i\rangle=0$, $\langle z_i^2\rangle=1$.*

It seems this notation has dual meaning: both quadratic variation and expectation.

Comment: It is the quadratic variation of an Ito's process: $<X>_t:=\int_0^t\sigma_s^2ds$

Comment: @FrancescoTotti This is one possible interpretation. However, I don't think that this is it. The notation seems to come from physics. I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The angle-bracket process is known as the predictable quadratic variation, whereas the straight-bracket process is the quadratic variation. For continuous processes, e.g. driven by a Brownian Motion, these 2 are equal but they might differ for jump-diffusions. This [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902886/angle-bracket-and-sharp-bracket-for-discontinuous-processes) from Math Stack Exchange should be helpful.

Comment: Pls also see here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/how-to-comprehend-this-notation

Comment: @Magicisinthechain This is useful! I hadn't seen that answer. So $\langle \delta S^2 \rangle $ means $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[d\langle S \rangle_t]$ (where inside the expectation I have the quadratic variation) ?

Comment: This is a constant source of confusion, particularly because the process for S remains vague! But I think quadratic variation is meant, even though the surrounding text talks about variance.